# Use Linq to create an inner join on data from SQL Server and Excel

Tags: c#, excel, linq, datacontext

Trying to use Linq to create an inner join on data from SQL Server and Excel. I can query each source independently but get an error when joining sources. The error returned is

> An IQueryable that returns a self-referencing Constant expression is not supported.

What does that mean and how can I fix the method?

```
/// <summary>
/// LINQ inner join to Excel query 
/// Sends the results of the query to a dataGridView.
/// Requires a DATAContext to talk to SQL Server.
/// Uses Linq to Excel to talk to Excel
/// </summary>
private void QueryDatabase()
{
    var excelFile = @"C:\Test\Cad_Database.xlsx";
    var excel = new ExcelQueryFactory(excelFile);

    GdaDataContext gda= new GdaDataContext();

    var query = from f in gda.DirectoryAnalysis
                join e in excel.Worksheet("Sheet1") on f.Fullname equals e["FullPath"]
                select new
                {
                    f.Fullname,
                    f.Name,
                    ExcelFullName =  e["FullPath"],
                    DrawingTitle = e["Drawing Title"],
                    DrawingNumber = e["Drawing Number"],
                    DrawingDate = e["Drawing Date"],
                    VendorName = e["Vendor Name"],
                    f.DA_Id
                };

    foreach (var item in query)
    {
        LogWriter.LogEvent($"{item.Fullname}    {item.ExcelFullName}   {item.DrawingTitle} {item.DrawingTitle}", "InnerJoinLinqToExcel");
    }
    dataGridView1.DataSource = query;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what gda.DirectoryAnalysis is but since you are joining two different data sources it makes sense to make an in-memory join (of course take care you are not joining too much data in memory). So perhaps changing the 4th line to `var query = from f in gda.DirectoryAnalysis.ToList()` could work ?